# How to copy and paste without change excel's cell category

Tags: excel, copy-paste, xls

I have a spreadsheet where all cells are text category, when I copy and paste from another spreadsheet into mine, all the cells affected have their category changed and sometimes the format of data too, the problem is that is not required for the client to know how to special paste so he could insert only values, so by not knowing how to perform this he ends up breaking this whole system functionlality.

Is there a way to configure cell as not available for category changes, or automatically copy only values as text instead of overwriting the whole cell.

I need my cells as they are, having it's cells category always as text

Comment: Can someone please explain me what an `Excel cell category` or a `cell's category` is?

Comment: right click on a cell and select format cell, u'll see the categories:

General, Text, Number, Date, Time, Special, Customized, Scientific and others

Comment: Oh, you are talking about the [NumberFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-numberformat-property-excel). Got it. No, you cannot prevent that. The only option you have is to capture the `Worksheet_Change()` event, use `Undo` to undo the user's last action and then redo it with VBA (manually). This means in essence that you have to capture the sheet before the undo and then redo cell by cell in the way you want it (possibly preserving formulas, number formats, references, range names, etc.).